# Update in grub.cfg file for loading new kernel image in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: grub, linux-kernel, ubuntu-11.04

I am new to Linux. I am compiling Linux kernel (ver: 2.6.34.12) in gcc in traditional manner in VMware machine in Ubuntu (kernel version - 2.6.38-8-generic) 11.04 version. I am unable to find, where to update about newly compiled kernel in the `grub.cfg` file. I updated the newly created image version name in the existing image. Then VMware didn't able to load new kernel. I have searched in internet but I didn't find. So anyone can help me, to update in the `grub.cfg` and to successfully load new kernel. Few things about what I have done:

1. Make bzImage to create image file.
2. Make modules_install && make install to install modules and then
3. `sudo mkinitramfs -o initramfs.img-2.6.34 2.6.34`. Then
4. `sudo gedit grub.cfg`. In that at the mementry I updated the version of vmlinuz and initrd from 2.6.38-8 to 2.6.34.12.

This is I have done.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

The first command updates the grub and the grub.conf file. The second command installs the updated grub onto `/dev/sda`, which usually contains the Master Boot Record.

Answer (score 0):

Run these command in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open. Click on *Recommended repair.*

[image: Boot repair]

This will update `grub.cfg`.